# using _.map and async.map together

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, underscore.js, node-async

I'm using both `_.map` and `async.map` in the Node portion of an application I'm working on. I'm running into some confusion while using these libraries together.

I have an array of arrays called `results` which looks something like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
```

I would like to use `_.map` to access each inner array, and then `async.map` to make an API call for each value within each of these inner arrays. I would then like to use the results of this API call to replace each integer within my inner arrays with an object.

So at the end my array of arrays of integers will instead be an array of arrays of objects based on API call results.

```
[[{id: 1, email: 'test@example.com', state: 'active'}], ...]
```

This is the current code I have, and I believe I'm on the right path. My first `console.log` gives me the object I'm aiming for, but the second simply returns the integer:

```
_.map(results, function(result) {
  async.map(result, function(user, callback) {
    db.users.getById(user, function(err, userDetails) {
      if (err) {
        callback(null, null);
      } else {
        user = _.pick(userDetails, 'id', 'email', 'state');
        console.log(user);
      }
    });
    console.log(user);
  })
});
```

Comment: where are you logging it?

Comment: @Mathletics, Added logs to the code in my original question.

Comment: You're logging `user` before the async operation `getById` has completed, so of course it's still the input.

Answer (score 0):

This is asynchronous, so, you will get the final result in a callback only.

You should pass 3 parameters to `async.map(array, iterator, callback)`

```
async.map(results, userArrayHandler, function(err, yourFinalArray) {
    console.log(yourFinalArray);
});

function userArrayHandler(userArray, callback) {
    async.map(userArray, getUser, function(err, results) {
        callback(null, results);
    });
}

function getUser(userId, callback) {
    db.users.getById(userId, function(err, userDetails) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            var user = _.pick(userDetails, 'id', 'email', 'state');
            callback(null, user);
        }
    });
}
```

using `async.map` for both inner and outer array instead of `_.map` will be convenient.

Answer (score 0):

From [docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#map):

```
_.map(results, function(result) {
  async.map(result, function(user, callback) {
    db.users.getById(user, function(err, userDetails) {
      callback(err, _.pick(userDetails, 'id', 'email', 'state'));
    });
  }, function(err, users){
    // here you will have your populated array of (arrays of) users
  })
});
```

But soon you'll find [Promise.all](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) more expressive in this regard.